# Randomly choose between calling two methods

Tags: java, random

I am creating a math game for my son that follows a story.
I have two methods that will present him with a question.
The first is named subtraction and second is named addition.
Currently I just call a method at a certain point in the story,
but I would prefer to randomly chose either the subtraction or addition method so it is less predictable.

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: Have you ever noticed class `Random`?

Comment: What's your class structure like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`java.util.Random#nextBoolean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean--):

```
// should only be done once, in some initialization block
Random myRand = new Random();     

// Then, once you have your Random instance:
if (myRand.nextBoolean()) {
    addition();
} else {
    subtraction();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mureinik, that works just the way I wanted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer of Mureinik:

You could also use the `Random` class in order to choose between more than two methods, in case you'd want to add multiplication and division, as well.

It could look like this then:

```
Random myRand = new Random();     
randomInteger = myRand.nextInt(4);

if (randomInteger == 0) {
  addition();
} else if (randomInteger == 1) {
  subtraction();
} else if (randomInteger == 2) {
  multiplication();
} else if (randomInteger == 3) {
  division();
}
```

Alternatively, a switch statement would be appropriate of course.

Comment: Thanks Barbarossa, I am sure that will come into play eventually.